# Obtener los valores de una tienda de Vuex en vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Quiero acceder a los valores del state desde un guard.

testo esta en mi store de vuex

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist'
import auth from './Modules/auth'
import system from './Modules/system'
Vue.use(Vuex)

const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
  key: 'dashboard',
  storage: window.localStorage
})

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {
    auth,
    system
  },
  plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin]
})
```

Y esto en mi vue-router

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Login from '../views/auth/Login.vue'
import AuthGuard from './guards/AuthGuard'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [

  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login,
    beforeEnter: AuthGuard.guest,
    meta: {
      layout: 'blank'
    }
  },
]


const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router;
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en el guard

```
import store from '../../store/Modules/auth'

class AuthGuard {
    async guest(to, from, next) {
        console.log(store);
        next();

    }
}

export default new AuthGuard;
```

Esto me regresa la tienda sin los valores que están guardados en el local storage.
No se como puedo acceder a los valores de la tienda. ya intente con **this.$store, mapState, mapGetters** y no funciona.

Necesito los valores de la tienda para hacer la logica de los guards.

Answer (score 0):

Al storage puedes acceder como siempre se accede desde JS, pero si lo que quieres es acceder al valor que tiene algún estado de tu tienda, puedes hacer:

```
// importas el estado
import state from '../store/modules/auth'
...
...
  if (!state.tu_estado) {
    return next(...)
  }
```